# Kafka's Consumer can't start

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, flume

I type the command line as below.but it show it is unable to connect to localhost:2181.  I have started the zookeeper.

bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper --localhost:2181 --topic pain --from-beginning

```
Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException: Unable to connect to --localhost:2181
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:66)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:876)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:171)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:126)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:143)
at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.create(ConsumerConnector.scala:94)
at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:145)
at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: --localhost
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1252)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1164)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.init(StaticHostProvider.java:61)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:445)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:380)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:64)
... 9 more


[root@crxy2 kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0]# jps
5487 QuorumPeerMain
5862 Jps
5518 Kafka

[root@crxy2 kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0]# bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
pain
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic pain --from-beginning`

Note the `--zookeeper localhost:2181` instead of `--zookeeper --localhost:2181`

Answer (score 0):

Try following command:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --topic pain --from beginning
```

Here I have assumed that one of your kafka brokers or kafka servers are running at localhost : 9093

if not provide address to any one alive kafka broker for parameter 
    --bootstrap-server

Comment: Just checkout the port number : its 9092 in my case. Look in kafka.properties file and search for  #listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092